# How to remove no longer valid Gauges

Tags: java, session, prometheus

I use the Prometheus Java Client to export session information of my application. We want to show how long sessions have been idle.

The problem is that we have a maximum of 1000 sessions and sessions are removed after a certain period. Unfortunately they do not disappear from Prometheus:

[image: Current and expired sessions]

My code looks like this:

```
static final Gauge sessionInactivity = Gauge.build()
    .name("sessions_inactivity_duration")
    .labelNames("internal_key", "external_key", "browser")
    .help("Number of milliseconds a certain session has been inactive")
    .register();

sessionInactivity.labels(internalKey, externalKey, browser).set(inactivityTime);
```

I tried to do `sessionInactivity.clear()` during scrapes but obviously this does not empty the content of the Gauge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of per-request handling is not suited to a metric system like Prometheus. This would be considered profiling, for which something more custom would be in order.

It's also recommend to export the timestamp for this sort of thing, not how long ago it was. This is resilient to the thing updating the time no longer updating, and you can do the subtraction from `time()` on the Prometheus end.

Comment: Understood, but is there no concept to remove a Gauge ? I have another scenario where I need to gather statistics for browsers which I will express using a label. I would prefer not having to set them simply to zero.

Comment: There is a way, but it's only really there for unitesting. That's also a use case for which Prometheus is not suited, for event logging you want something like the ELK stack.

Comment: I am still trying to figure out if my other scenario is a good fit for Prometheus or not. I clearly understood the timestamp part, I will change this. Can you tell me some (more) specific reasons why my approach for the sessions is not suited for Prometheus ? Is it because of the huge number of possible `internal_key`s that will go into the thousands although there can't be more than 1000 sessions at one time ? I can create another question for my second scenario, if you prefer this just give me a sign

Comment: The number of sessions is one reason, but also what they represent. Prometheus metrics you might extract out of that would be the total number of sessions, oldest session or average session ago.

Comment: I added another question which describes my scenario. I think it is different from what we already discussed. I would like to hear your opinion because I do not yet have a sense of where I hit the "critical mass" for Prometheus -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45199443/best-practice-for-storing-up-front-unknown-but-limited-in-amount-gauges

Comment: How is "there is a way but I'm not telling" the accepted answer?

Answer (score 4):

The `Gauge` class has a `remove` method which has the same signature as the `labels` method. For your specific example, removing the metrics associated with that gauge would look like this

```
sessionInactivity.remove(internalKey, externalKey, browser);
```

The client library [documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/writing_clientlibs/#labels) states:

> Metrics with labels SHOULD support a remove() method with the same
> signature as labels() that will remove a Child from the metric no
> longer exporting it, and a clear() method that removes all Children
> from the metric. These invalidate caching of Children.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are registrating the gauge, you need to remove the gauges which are expired from the registry.

```
protected MeterRegistry registry;

  ...
  static final Gauge sessionInactivity = Gauge.build()
    .name("sessions_inactivity_duration")
    .labelNames("internal_key", "external_key", "browser")
    .help("Number of milliseconds a certain session has been inactive")
    .register(registry); // use registry

  ...
  // remove expired gauges from registry
  registry.remove(sessionInactivity);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to find a solution for this:

```
metric{version="1.0.0",} 1.0
metric{version="1.0.1",} 1.0
```

I needed to remove the old metric if exists.

```java
Gauge gauge = Gauge.builder(fildName, myModelClassObject, MyModelClass::getFieldValue)
        .tags(tags)
        .strongReference(true)
        .register(Metrics.globalRegistry);
```

Solved saving it on a `Map<String, ObjectWithTagsAndGauge>` and when comes a different event I remove the other one before send the new metric with:

```java
//if map contains key
ObjectWithTagsAndGauge obj = map.get(key);
//my conditions with tags
Metrics.globalRegistry.remove(obj.getGauge()); // get the Gauge object to be removed
```

Hope it helps